# Headphone jack potentially getting loose

Tags: laptop, audio, headphones, headphone-jack

So I am using a lenovo T460 laptop. I have plugged in my headphones this morning and I noticed it comes in and comes out very easily. It does not happen before. Usually if I need to take my headphones out of my laptop I need to pull it with additional force (just like all devices). When I wigggle the headphone wire, I noticed it moves around a lot inside the laptop.  What's wierd here is it is still working perfectly fine.

I think the headphone jack is getting loose now. But it is still working. Should I take any action or do nothing?

Answer (score 3):

Below is a diagram of a headphone jack:

[image: Headphone jack]

As you can see, there are two metal clips that hold the headphone plug. Over time and use, the metal will start bending outwards and lose its original shape.

Best bet to fit this is to DIY, open up your laptop and bend it inwards, or send it to a repair shop.

Preventative measures include plugging & unplugging your headphones only when needed.

Comment: "plugging & unplugging your headphones only when needed" - That is a problem. I've plugged and unplugged my headphones so many times right now just to test my theory that something is wrong. Did I intentionly made it worse?

Comment: When you say "Over time and use", are you saying this will eventually happen?

Comment: By 'only when needed', I mean use it normally, and don't plug and unplug several times just to test.Yes, with every device I've had, all the ports were very sturdy when I first bought it, and they do become loose.